# How to Check field value on "RunTime"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i have a personalized list let's call it "tasks" with a field "assigned to", the user can add

a task with empty "assigned to" but after 7 days if the user didnt complete this information

an email will be sent to the admin.

How can i perform this?

"Sorry for my bad english"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easy to do with a list workflow in SharePoint designer.

In SharePoint Designer 2010, it should look something like this:
[image: Example workflow for sending e-mail]

Make this workflow run when an item is added to the list, and you should be all set.

There are of course many different ways to do this, but I believe this is the simplest one.